# java string scramble

Tags: java, encryption

I am currently working on a program that takes user data (name, address, phone). I want to make the data unreadable when I save it. Since it won't be a released program, I don't want to use a cipher that is too complicated, just a simple and quick scramble/unscramble algorithm.

Comment: What does it matter how complicated the algorithm is; you don't plan on implementing it yourself do you?  Java has a very extensive library ecosystem that you should get used to consulting first.  Most of the popular libraries are free with permissive licenses.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a class (let's say `Foo`) and create instances of that class those which can hold the data, then put the objects into a list. After that, save the list object as a binary file. Something like this:

```
public static void saveObject(List<Foo> obj, String filePath)
{
    OutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        os.writeObject(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    finally
    {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can load it like:

```
public static List<Foo> loadObject(String filePath)
{
    List<Foo> obj = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        obj = (List<Foo>) is.readObject();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
    finally
    {
        is.close();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Note that you need to implement the `Serializable` interface to use this object serialization.

Comment: That would still make the file pretty easy to read. There is no scrambling of the object data performed when an object is serialized. No worries, you could still be able to put a CipherOutputStream with an AES Cipher between the ObjectOutputStream and the FileOutputStream. For simple obfuscation, use a static key and ECB encoding (and PKCS5Padding). Before choosing this option though make sure you understand the pro's and con's of serialization; e.g. change of internal program structures may be reflected on disk.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to understand that its a matter of strength of your algorithm, because according to your post, you do need some way of encryption/decryption.
You can think about a lot of ways to "hide" your data but this "defense" can be broken in a relatively easy way... So its up to you to decide.
The easiest implementations are (naive):
- substitute each letter in your string with some number.
- play with ascii values of your letters in string.

Again the real question here is whether it is good enough??? 
From the point of view of "security" - definitely not.